# Lost layers after upgrading cadence into 6.1.5

Tags: cadence

I was using an older version of cadence with LSW in a seperate window. After upgrading cadence into the new version, I am unable to access the layers like: met1, met2. I enabled valid layers, but they are only some useless ones.

[image: Layer pane]

How can I enable the old layers?

Answer (score 1):

This was due to attaching a wrong technology file while creating the library. Choosing TECHc25b4 solved the issue.